# How do I check to see if a function returned T or F after the fact?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is what I am working with:

```
def yes_or_no(answer):
    if answer == 'yes':
        return True
    elif answer == 'no':
        return False
```

How would I get some later code to check and see what this returns?
Aka what would I write?

Comment: If answer is neither `yes` or `no`, this function will return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Just test for truth:

```
if yes_or_no(answer):
    # user picked yes
else:
    # user picked no
```

You may want to think about what should happen if `answer` is neither `'yes'` or `'no'` however. Perhaps you already have checked earlier on in your code this is the case, but you may as well just use:

```
def yes_or_no(answer):
    return answer == 'yes'
```

and be done with it; now it'll *always* return a boolean. `True` in case of `'yes'`, and `False` otherwise, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer - it's a cleaner approach by far. But if you're determined to do something with your function:

```
def yes_or_no(answer):
    if answer == 'yes':
        return True
    elif answer == 'no':
        return False

answer = raw_input('yes or no?')
x = yes_or_no(answer)
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, you should validate the user input. Never expect user input to match your expectations if they are not enforced. This code below uses a loop that keeps asking the user until the input matches `yes` or `no`.

```
def yes_or_no():
    while True:
        text = input('yes or no? ')
        if text == 'yes':
            return True
        elif text == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print('Invalid input')
```

You can now assign the return value of the function to a new variable and use that inside of an if-statement.

```
answer = yes_or_no()
if answer == True:
    print('Answered yes')
else:
    print('Answered no')
```

You can also directly use the return value inside of an if-statement.

```
if yes_or_no() == True:
    print('Answered yes')
else:
    print('Answered no')
```

The Python interpreter evaluates the condition of an if-statement to a boolean value, `True` or `False`. In the above case, the `==` is either true or false. But since `yes_or_no()` already returns a boolean, we can use it directly.

```
if yes_or_no():
    print('Answered yes')
else:
    print('Answered no')
```

Since your function returns a boolean value representing a confirmation of the user, you might also rename the function to something like `user_confirmed()`. Intuitively, `user_confirmed()` is something that can be true or false, while `yes_or_no()` can't since one of them always happens. The if-statement reads more natural then.

Answer (score -1):

Im really new here so i ight be totally wrong (or just posting a different, and probably worse, version of what someone else already said, but you could do:

```
yes_or_no = raw_input("say yes or no")

if yes_or_no == "yes":
    variable = True
elif yes_or_no == "no":
    variable = False

print variable
```

If this is totally wrong or not what you were looking for then i am sorry.

Comment: Why did someone downvote me? If it didn't work then tell me why at least.